# apple music - in browser - how add track to playlist?

Tags: music

Using music.apple.com in Chrome

I see my playlists... I can look up songs... but there is no option to add a song to a playlist?

On my phone I can do this, but searching for music on the phone is tedious. (Also, I just found a track that comes up on the music.apple.com web site, but not in the phone app on android!)

Is the ability to create and manage playlists missing in the web version, or am I looking in the wrong place?